# How do I enable the curl progress bar in cygwin?

Tags: curl, cygwin

When you curl a file, you get this progress bar whether you're uploading or downloading a file.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   401  100   401    0     0   5141      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8531
```

I'm trying to curl a file on my personal laptop using cygwin and no progress bar is showing up. I checked the manual and by all accounts a progress bar should show up but it doesn't. I had to install the curl package for cygwin so maybe I edited the settings. All other stdout from normal shell commands and from other languages shows up. curl can write http gets to stdout too.

```
curl -O http://blah.blah.com/blah/blah.png
```

The file gets there fine and I can open and view it. There's just no meter.

It's just a minor inconvenience and was wondering if anyone knew how to deal with it.

I got curl sometime this summer so I don't think my version is very old. Curl does show the progress bar works fine when I run it from a windows command prompt.

TL:DR, how do I get the progress bar to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl will only display a progress meter for a substantial download. If I download the [StackOverflow About page](https://stackoverflow.com/about), for example, it just downloads with no progress meter. If, however, I download an [Ubuntu ISO](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/releases.ubuntu.com/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso), I do see that progress meter:

```
$ curl -O https://stackoverflow.com/about

$ curl -O 'http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/releases.ubuntu.com/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  6  695M    6 42.6M    0     0  8738k      0  0:01:21  0:00:05  0:01:16 8858k
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above two commands and got the same output you did. There's probably a setting for the minimum size that curl will display a progress bar and you've set me on the right track.